# Uncomon behavior of UIButton in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm creating a simple story game, where you have Description of the situation and also 2 actions. Next situation is depending on what is your choice.

Data storing class
'''
class StoryData {

```
var storyText: String
var answerA: String
var answerB: String
var nextStoryA: StoryData?
var nextStoryB: StoryData?

init(text: String, answerAText: String, answerBText: String) {
    storyText = text
    answerA = answerAText
    answerB = answerBText
}
```

}
'''

Programm
'''
class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var Story: [StoryData] = []
var currentStory: StoryData = StoryData(text: "", answerAText: "", answerBText: "")

// UI Elements linked to the storyboard
@IBOutlet weak var topButton: UIButton!         // Has TAG = 1
@IBOutlet weak var bottomButton: UIButton!      // Has TAG = 2
@IBOutlet weak var storyTextView: UILabel!




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Story data storing
    Story.append(StoryData(text: "Your car has blown a tire on a winding road in the middle of nowhere with no cell phone reception. You decide to hitchhike. A rusty pickup truck rumbles to a stop next to you. A man with a wide brimmed hat with soulless eyes opens the passenger door for you and asks: \"Need a ride, boy?\".", answerAText: "I\'ll hop in. Thanks for the help!", answerBText: "Better ask him if he\'s a murderer first."))

    Story.append(StoryData(text: "He nods slowly, unphased by the question.", answerAText: "At least he\'s honest. I\'ll climb in.", answerBText: "Wait, I know how to change a tire."))

    Story.append(StoryData(text: "As you begin to drive, the stranger starts talking about his relationship with his mother. He gets angrier and angrier by the minute. He asks you to open the glovebox. Inside you find a bloody knife, two severed fingers, and a cassette tape of Elton John. He reaches for the glove box.", answerAText: "I love Elton John! Hand him the cassette tape.", answerBText: "It\'s him or me! You take the knife and stab him."))

    Story.append(StoryData(text: "What? Such a cop out! Did you know traffic accidents are the second leading cause of accidental death for most adult age groups?", answerAText: "", answerBText: ""))

    Story.append(StoryData(text: "As you smash through the guardrail and careen towards the jagged rocks below you reflect on the dubious wisdom of stabbing someone while they are driving a car you are in.", answerAText: "", answerBText: ""))

    Story.append(StoryData(text: "You bond with the murderer while crooning verses of \"Can you feel the love tonight\". He drops you off at the next town. Before you go he asks you if you know any good places to dump bodies. You reply: \"Try the pier.\"", answerAText: "", answerBText: ""))


    // Story tree creating
    Story[0].nextStoryA = Story[2]
    Story[0].nextStoryB = Story[1]
    Story[1].nextStoryA = Story[2]
    Story[1].nextStoryB = Story[3]
    Story[2].nextStoryA = Story[5]
    Story[2].nextStoryB = Story[4]

    currentStory = Story[0]

    updateUI()

}


// User presses one of the buttons
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if sender.tag == 1{

        currentStory = currentStory.nextStoryA ?? currentStory

    }
    else if sender.tag == 2{

        currentStory = currentStory.nextStoryB ?? currentStory

    }

    updateUI()

}

func updateUI() {

    storyTextView.text = currentStory.storyText
    topButton.setTitle(currentStory.answerA, for: .normal)
    bottomButton.setTitle(currentStory.answerB, for: .normal)

    if topButton.currentTitle == ""{
        topButton.frame.size.height = 0
        topButton.frame.size.width = 0
    }
    if bottomButton.currentTitle == ""{
        bottomButton.frame.size.height = 0
        bottomButton.frame.size.width = 0
    }

}
```

}
'''

When it comes to the end of the game Buttons are not disappear.
They have to disappear when the title got empty value.

Comment: Don't hide a button by changing its size. Hide a button using the `isHidden` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking empty text in any of your `buttons` and updating the `frames`, you can simply **hide/show** the `buttons` based on your **model values**.

Simply update the `updateUI()` method with the below 2 lines, i.e.

```
func updateUI() {
    storyTextView.text = currentStory.storyText
    topButton.setTitle(currentStory.answerA, for: .normal)
    bottomButton.setTitle(currentStory.answerB, for: .normal)

    //Add below 2 lines instead
    topButton.isHidden = currentStory.answerA.isEmpty
    bottomButton.isHidden = currentStory.answerB.isEmpty
}
```

Let me know in case you still face any issues.

Comment: It works! But still, I want to know why the previous version was bad.

Comment: @MaxPan If this answer doesn't fully answer your question (why didn't your code work), then don't yet accept the answer. Wait until an answer fully answers your question before accepting.

Comment: @MaxPan set `clipToBounds` of your buttons to `true` and your previous version will work as well.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to hide button using below code,

```
yourButtonName.isHidden = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the content of updateUI() function with the code below.

```
func updateUI() {

    storyTextView.text = currentStory.storyText
    topButton.setTitle(currentStory.answerA, for: .normal)
    bottomButton.setTitle(currentStory.answerB, for: .normal)

    topButton.isHidden = topButton.currentTitle.isEmpty
    bottomButton.isHidden = bottomButton.currentTitle.isEmpty

}
```